# How to make column inside column table using multicell in dpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a trouble with my code that I want to make a column inside column table using `fpdf`.

That's the example

[image]

This is my code that I have tried:

```
public function cetak_dokumentasi()
{
    $this->fpdf = new Fpdf;
    $this->fpdf->AddPage("P", 'A4');
    $this->fpdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 11);
    $this->fpdf->Cell(0, 8, 'Data Siswa', 0, 1, 'C');
    $this->fpdf->SetWidths(array(15, 35, 50));
    $this->fpdf->SetAligns(array("C", "C", "C"));
    $this->fpdf->Row(array(
        "\nNo",
        "\nNama",
        "\nKeterangan"
    ));

    $this->fpdf->SetAligns(array("C", "C", "C"));
    $this->fpdf->Row(array(
        "\n1",
        "\nBoy",
        "\Mapel"
    ));
    $this->fpdf->Output();
    exit;
}
```

And picture below is the example of the code:

[image]